# Alternative to Pixel Saver (remove title bar and place buttons in top bar)

Tags: wingpanel, themes, window-manager, software-recommendation

I've moved from Fedora with gnome-shell 3.16. I'm seeking a plugin that works like [Pixel Saver](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/723/pixel-saver/), which generally removes the title bar and places its buttons in the top bar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not possible for two reasons:

1. Window decorations are now drawn by the application itself. There no longer is a separate title bar.
2. The panel does not support such an API.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, Pixel Saver stop working in new Gnome

But [Unite](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/1287/unite/) works well on Ubuntu 19.04. One more alternative is [gtk-title-bar](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/1732/gtk-title-bar/)