# Is it possible to get rid of the title bar for not only Firefox but all applications?

Tags: themes, user-interface, pantheon

For example:

## DeaDBeeF music player

From this:[image]

To this:(edited by GIMP)[image]

Comment: how you got screenshots ?

Comment: press Alt+PrintScreen for one window, press PrintScreen for whole desktop(only one desktop)

Comment: o_O nope, I mean, you have screenshots with desired result, how?

Comment: They aren't real, I edit them by GIMP.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From answer in [other post](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/3280/pixelsaver-alternative):

No, its not possible for *all*.

> Window decorations are now drawn by the application itself. There no longer is a separate title bar.

Comment: What!! The DeaDBeeF developer told me to ask the elementary OS developers...

Comment: So who can actually do that?

Comment: @JulianLai There's nothing elementary OS can do about the elements inside an app. If the developers of an app wanted to put a menubar into the window decoration, they would have to do that themselves.